# remove unique lines from text file using perl

Tags: perl

I'm doing some filtering on a text file with multiple columns in perl

The file has the following format:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4 
1   ..  ..  ..
2   ..  ..  ..
3   ..  ..  ..
3   ..  ..  ..
3   ..  ..  ..
```

I want to delete all the lines that have a unique value in column 1. So the output should be this:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4
3   ..  ..  ..
3   ..  ..  ..
3   ..  ..  ..
```

I'm doing different filtering steps with this file. This is the script with which I'm working

```
my $ DATA
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
    unless ($filename) {
        print "Enter filename:\n";
        $filename = <STDIN>;
        chomp $filename;
     }
open($DATA,'<',$filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
open($OUT,'+>',"processed.txt") or die "Can't write new file: $!";

while(<$DATA>){
    next if /^\s*#/; 
    print $OUT $_;
    }

close $OUT;
```

As you can see, I'm working in a while loop in which I already used the    next command to remove the comment lines from the file. Now I want to add to this loop the command to remove all the lines with a unique value in column 1.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the lines come out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly stolen from ikegami and mattan:

```
print "header: ", scalar(<>);
print "multis: \n";

my %seen;
while (<>) {
   next if /^\s*#/;
   my ($id) = /^(\S+)/;
   ++$seen{$id}{count};
   if (1 == $seen{$id}{count}) {
      # store first occurrence
      $seen{$id}{line} = $_;
   } elsif (2 == $seen{$id}{count}) {
      # print first & second occurrence
      print $seen{$id}{line};
      print $_;
   } else {
      # print Third ... occurrence
      print $_;
   }
}
```

but keeps order and uses just one loop.

**Later:**

After thinking twice about

> yes, they [the lines] should stay the same as they are now, which is in numerical
>   order [of ids]

I can give back the solen goods:

```
print "header: ", scalar(<>);
print "multis: \n";

my $ol = scalar(<>);                      # first/old line
my $oi = 0 + (split(" ", $ol, 2))[0];     # first/old id
my $bf = -1;                              # assume old line must be printed
do {
   my $cl = scalar(<>);                   # current line
   my $ci = 0 + (split(" ", $cl, 2))[0];  # current id
   if ($oi != $ci) {                      # old and current id differ
      $oi = $ci;                          #   remember current/first line of current id
      $ol = $cl;                          #   current id becomes old
      $bf = -1;                           #   assume first/old line must be printed
   } else {                               # old and current id are equal
      if ($bf) {                          #    first/old line of current id must be printed
        print $ol;                        #      do it
        $bf = 0;                          #      but not again
      }
      print $cl;                          #    print current line for same id
   }
} while (! eof());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done neatly with [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile), which allows you to map an array to a text file so that removing elements from the array also removes lines from the file.

This program takes two passes through the file: the first one to count the number of occcurrences of each value of the first field, and the second to delete the lines where that field is unique in the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'textfile.txt' or die $!;

my %index;

for (@file) {
  $index{$1}++ if /^(\d+)/;
}

for (my $i = 1; $i < @file; ++$i) {
  if ( $file[$i] =~ /^(\d+)/ and $index{$1} == 1 ) {
    splice @file, $i, 1;
    --$i;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Tie::File can be notoriously slow](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1000412) with 'large' files.

Comment: @Kenosis: Please don't perpetuate these scare stories. People are inclined to avoid any technique that is said to be less than the fastest possible, even when it is the difference between one millisecond and ten milliseconds run time. `Tie::File` is highly desirable and perfectly adequate for the huge majority of practical applications.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %id_count;
while(my $line = <$DATA>){
    next if $line =~ /^\s*#/; 
    my ($id) = split(/\s+/,$line,1);
    $id_count{$id}{lines} .= $line;
    $id_count{$id}{counter}++;
}

print $OUT join("",map { $id_count{$_}{lines} } grep { $id_count{$_}{counter} ne "1" } keys %id_count);
```

Edit:
If you want to keep the lines sorted, just add a `sort` before the `grep` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get rid of the extraneous stuff from your program.

```
while (<>) {
   next if /^\s*#/; 
   print;
}
```

Ok, it looks like you didn't even extra the value of the first column.

```
my ($id) = /^(\S+)/;
```

We don't know if there's going to be duplicates before reading on, so we need to store lines for later use.

```
push @{ $by_id{$id} }, $_;
```

Once we've read through the file, we print out the lines for ids with more than one line.

```
for my $id (keys(%by_id)) {
    print @{ $by_id{$id} } if @{ $by_id{$id} } > 1;
}
```

Finally, you failed to handle the header, which can be done using

```
print scalar(<>);
```

Altogether, we get

```
print scalar(<>);

my %by_id;
while (<>) {
   next if /^\s*#/; 
   my ($id) = /^(\S+)/;
   push @{ $by_id{$id} }, $_;
}

for my $id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%by_id)) {
    print @{ $by_id{$id} } if @{ $by_id{$id} } > 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
script.pl file.in >processed.txt
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. All the duplicate lines (with the same values in column1) are filtered out. The lines with the unique values in column1 stay in my file. So I get exactly the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Oops, and you want to keep *all* of the duplicates, not just all but one.

Comment: yes indeed, I want to keep all the duplicates and remove all the unique.

Comment: @user1987607, Fixed. Does the order of the ids need to be preserved? Do you want the ids in ascending order? or is the order unimportant?

Comment: yes, they should stay the same as they are now, which is in numerical order

Comment: They are now output in ascending order (regardless of the original order).