# Remove/Extract rows based on Unique/duplicate Id from a CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

Depending on how you look at it I need to remove rows based on if the Id is unique **or** extract rows if the Id has duplicates (keeping all duplicates).
And I'm unsure/don't have enough knowledge of Perl to accomplish this. I've found similair topics but didn't have much succes. These are the examples I'm using [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592178/1465863), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900461/perl-getting-unique-values-from-file-column?rq=1) and [example 3](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch04_07.htm). In a previous problem someone showed me a solution with the List::MoreUtils module, so I could merge values with a common Id. This is not the case now, this one is removing rows if the id is unique. I know I can probably do this with the List::MoreUtils module but I want to do it without. This is my dummy data (copied example data from other question since the data doesn't matter), here you can see what I'm after. Order is not important.

**Before:**

```
Cat_id;Cat_name;Id;Name;Amount;Colour;Bla
101;Fruits;50010;Grape;500;Red;1
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;500;Red;1
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;500;White;1
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;1000;Red;1
101;Fruits;50030;Banana;1000;Green;1
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;500;Green;1
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;1000;Red;1
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;100;Purple;1
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;200;Red;1
```

**After:**

```
Cat_id;Cat_name;Id;Name;Amount;Colour;Bla
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;500;Red;1
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;500;White;1
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;1000;Red;1
101;Fruits;50060;Apple;500;Green;1
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;1000;Red;1
201;Vegetables;60010;Carrot;100;Purple;1
101;Fruits;50020;Strawberry;200;Red;1
```

You can see that the rows of Grape and Banana with id 50010 and 50030 have been removed because there only exists one entry for both.

This is my script, I'm struggeling with the part where I select the unique values from the hash and to output them (taking the Text::CSV_XS module in account). Can someone show me how to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $inputfile = shift || die "Give input and output names!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output name!\n";

open (my $infile, '<:encoding(iso-8859-1)', $inputfile) or die "Sourcefile in use / not found :$!\n";
open (my $outfile, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $outputfile) or die "Outputfile in use :$!\n";

my $csv_in = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1,sep_char => ";",auto_diag => 1,always_quote => 1,eol => $/}); 
my $csv_out = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1,sep_char => "|",auto_diag => 1,always_quote => 1,eol => $/});

my $header = $csv_in->getline($infile);
$csv_out->print($outfile, $header);

my %data;

while (my $elements = $csv_in->getline($infile)){
    my @columns = @{ $elements };       
    my $id = $columns[2];
    push @{ $data{$id} }, \@columns;
}

for my $id ( sort keys %data ){                 # Sort not important
    if @{ $data{$id} } > 1                      # Here I have no idea anymore..
        $csv_out->print($outfile, \@columns);   #
}
```

Comment: This question looks oddly familiar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627669/merge-csv-rows-based-on-duplicate-key-and-combine-unique-values-using-perl-text/28673012#28673012

Comment: @Sobrique Agreed, almost the same.. I tried to work off of that one but that was merging fields if the id was the same and this one is removing rows if the id is unique

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading a hash with the entire dataset, I think I'd go ahead and read the file twice, loading a hash with just your `ID` values.  This will definitely take longer, but as your file grows, there may be disadvantages of having all of that data in memory.

That said, I did not use `Text::CSV_XS` but this is a **notional** idea of what I had in mind.

```
my %count;

open (my $infile, '<:encoding(iso-8859-1)', $inputfile) or die;
open (my $outfile, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $outputfile) or die;

while (<$infile>) {
  next if $. == 1;
  my ($id) = (split /;/, $_, 4)[2];
  $count{$id}++;
}

seek $infile, 0, 0;

while (<$infile>) {
  my @fields = split /;/;
  print $outfile join '|', @fields if $count{$fields[2]} > 1 or $. == 1;    
}

close $infile;
close $outfile;
```

The `$. == 1` at the end is so you don't lose your header row.

-- EDIT --

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $inputfile = shift || die "Give input and output names!\n";
my $outputfile = shift || die "Give output name!\n";

open (my $infile, '<:encoding(iso-8859-1)', $inputfile) or die;
open (my $outfile, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $outputfile) or die;

my $csv_in = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1,sep_char => ";",
    auto_diag => 1,always_quote => 1,eol => $/}); 
my $csv_out = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1,sep_char => "|",
    auto_diag => 1,always_quote => 1,eol => $/});

my ($count, %count) = (1);

while (my $elements = $csv_in->getline($infile)){
  $count{$$elements[2]}++;
}

seek $infile, 0, 0;

while (my $elements = $csv_in->getline($infile)){
  $csv_out->print($outfile, $elements)
    if $count{$$elements[2]} > 1 or $count++ == 1;
}

close $infile;
close $outfile;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have to use the Text::CSV_XS module (it's a sizeable file with the delimiter in the data). Do you have a suggestion on how do to it with the module?

Comment: I think the rest of your code was fine...  I was just being lazy to notionally describe how I would do it.  You can adopt the existing Text::CSV_XS exactly how you had it.  I've modified my response for this.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but now it says "Use of uninitialized value in hash element at line 27", as in: it has nothing to print.. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Jan.  Without seeing your data, I'm guessing, but my initial guess would be that you have a line in your first file (`$infile`) that is blank or otherwise doesn't have >= four columns of data, this making `$$elements[2]`.  Can you print to standard output (to debug) to see how many lines it it gets before it fields this error?  Or, just to debug, expose each of the variables on that line to see what they contain when the error is thrown (ie `print $elements $csv_out $outfile\n`).  I think it's safe to say %count has data.